# Rich javascript function findComponent

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, el

I am trying to add a dynamic onclick event using `rich:findComponent` as:

```
<font class="topFirstTablehdCategory2" style="font-size: 12px; cursor: pointer;" onclick="#{rich:findComponent('benchmarkEndDate').value = channelPerformanceController.resetDate}">
    RESET
</font>
```

But I am getting

```
com.sun.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered "=" at line 1, column 48.
```

What I am willing to do, is to set string value to a `rich:calender` whose id is `benchmarkEndDate` supplied from the field `resetDate` of `ChannelPerformanceController` class.

I also write a javascript method in the jsp page:

```
function setResetDate(id, date) {
    #{rich:findComponent('benchmarkEndDate').value} = date;
}
```

is not working. It is called as: `onclick="setResetDate('benchmarkEndDate', '#{channelPerformanceController.resetDate}')"`

It is rendering in browser as:

```
function setResetDate(id, date) {
        2011-03-24 00:00:00.0 = date;
}
```

This method:

```
function setResetDate(id, date) {
        document.getElementById(#{rich:clientId(id)}) = date;
}
```

is change into :

```
function setResetDate(id, date) {
        document.getElementById() = date;
}
```

What I am doing wrong? How can I achieve this?

Comment: did you try: function setResetDate(id, date) {
    "#{rich:findComponent('benchmarkEndDate').value}" = date;
} - note the quotes ive put around the expression

Comment: It is rendering as function setResetDate(id, date) { 
   "2011-03-24 00:00:00.0" = date; 
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- JavaScript is executed by the client.
- Expression Language expressions are evaluated on the server before the markup is sent to the browser.

---

`#{foo = bar}` is not a valid EL expression. `=` is not a valid operator in EL. EL does not have an assignment operator. The only way to assign values via EL is using a value binding in attributes that support them (almost exclusively via JSF input controls).

---

If this expression is evaluated:

```
#{rich:clientId(id)}
```

This expression will search the [request](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29), [session](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) and [application](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) scopes looking using `getAttribute("id")`, using managed bean mechanisms to create such a bean if it is defined with this id. When this is evaluated and returns null, nothing will be rendered.

---

If this expression is **not** evaluated:

```
#{rich:clientId(id)}
```

Then it is being placed in template text (probably in JSP 2.0/J2EE 1.4.)

There are two types of EL expression:

- `#{foo}` - *deferred expression*: only evaluated in attributes that allow them
- `${foo}` - *immediate expression*: allowed in template text

Beginning with JSP 2.1, it is a translation error to have a deferred expression in template text. From the JSP 2.1 specification:

> When used in template text in a JSP page, the `#{` character sequence
>   triggers a translation error, unless specifically allowed through a
>   configuration setup. This is because the `#{}` syntax is associated
>   exclusively with deferred-evaluation in JSP
>   2.1 and does not make sense in the context of template text (only
>   immediate evaluation using the `${expr}` syntax makes sense in
>   template text).
>
> In a tag file, `#{expr}` in template text is handled according to the
>   tag file’s JSP version: If the tag file’s JSP version is 2.0 or less,
>   `#{expr}` in template text will not cause any error. If the tag file’s
>   JSP version is equal to or greater than 2.1, `#{expr}` in template
>   text must cause an error, unless it has been escaped or the tag file
>   contains a `deferredSyntaxAllowedAsLiteral` tag directive attribute
>   set to `TRUE`.

Generally, `#{foo}` expressions must be in JSF control attributes only (for JSP views).

---

If you want to change a server-side value, use a form submit and action binding. This can be done via [AJAX](http://richfaces-showcase.appspot.com/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=commandButton&skin=blueSky) in RichFaces.